# Difference between events and change tokens in C#

Tags: c#, events

I am developing an C# application that loads some data from a file. Whenever the file is changed, the application needs to load the data and perform some actions. Watching the file was straight forward using the `FileSystemWatcher` class. Notifying the rest of the application was also straight forward using an `event`. However, when researching solutions, I found the [`IOptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1) interface, which uses an `OnChange` function instead of an event:

```cs
public IDisposable OnChange (Action<out TOptions, string> listener);
```

According to [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsMonitor.cs), the default implementation [`OptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsmonitor-1) watches some change tokens, connects them to an internal `_onChange` event, which then invokes the listeners. Doing further research, I stumbled over the [`IFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.ifileprovider) interface, which contains a `Watch` method that returns a change token:

```cs
public IChangeToken Watch (string filter);
```

I read the [`IChangeToken` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.ichangetoken) and the [*Detect changes with change tokens in ASP.NET Core* article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens). However, I dont see the advantage of change tokens over events. It seems to me that both change tokens and events provide the same functionality - notifying some listeners that something happened - while events are easier to implement and well-known. Why would I ever want to use change tokens when I can just use an event instead? Am I missing a crucial feature of change tokens?

Comment: Events are multicast (i.e. more than one listener), whereas Action<> is restricted to a single listener.   In the case of IOptionsMonitor, there would generally only be one listener (the consumer of the IOptions<> class), so an Action<> seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Neil The `OnChange` function can be called multiple times, with different Actions. So it is not restricted to a single listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IChangeToken` is another layer that allows to listen to some other object events without depending on it.

So when B want's to listen for changes in A using event - B have to know (depend on) A. But with `IChangeToken` A and B both relies on `IChangeToken`, but they do not need to know about each other at all

[source](https://developpaper.com/net-core-common-design-patterns-ichangetoken/)

Comment: Does this mean that a change token is basically an event that can be passed around to other objects?

Comment: @pschill Yes, and the other objects can rely just on "event", without knowing where it came from and what triggered it. It's more like an abstraction over events